# How to recover the default php.ini

Tags: php

I accidentally deleted `php.ini` from `/etc/php5/apache2`. How to recover it?

I tried to remove and install `php5` without luck.

Answer (score 14):

You can copy from /usr/share/php5/php.ini-production.

```
sudo cp /usr/share/php5/php.ini-production /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

Comment: For PHP 7.1, the file was located at `/usr/lib/php/7.1/php.ini-production` for me.

Comment: For PHP 8.1, the file is `/usr/lib/php/8.1/php.ini-production.cli`